# How to setup extra content-security-policy based on file type in koa?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

The goal is to setup special rules for svg files,

```
server {
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; child-src https://www.youtube.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; frame-src https://www.youtube.com; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com";

    location ~ \.svg$ {
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'";
    }
}
```

for the 1st rule, we can do

```
ctx.response.set('Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src ...');
```

How about the 2nd line for the svg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular expression

```
const svgPattern = /.+\.svg$/;
if (filename.test(svgPattern)) {
  // add required header
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get filename from ctx.response from koa ?

Comment: This depends on how do you serve this files, also you can use `ctx.request.url` because it should contain a filename